# Creating spreadsheet with OOXML & RGB color shows as hex 4 value instead of 3

Tags: colors, styles, openxml, rgb

I am creating a spreadsheet using OOXML. In the example spreadsheet I am referencing to compare my output versus Excel 2010's Output I see the following entry in styles.xml:

```
<font><sz val="11"/><color rgb="FFFF0000"/><name val="Calibri"/><family val="2"/><scheme val="minor"/></font>
```

My understanding of RGB colors is that they are usually represented as 3 numbers i.e. 255,0,0 or as Hex FF0000
But in the example spreadsheet I have it shows as rgb=FFFF0000 which I would read as 255,255,0,0
How is FFFF0000 derived from the color Red? 
It appears that a FF is inserted in front of the RGB hex value in all my colors, but I would prefer to know if this is part of the OOXML specifications before I assume something and later have issues with an incorrect assumption.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After some more research I have been able to answer my own question.
(Google ARGB for more info) 
The 1st hex character (additional one preceding the RGB hex value) is used to define the level of transparency.
This Hex value ranges from X'00' which means fully transparent to X'FF" means fully opaque